# Trouble understanding @extend in Sass ...

Tags: css, sass

Note: this is an example from an online course I am taking at codeschool.com ...

So in the _buttons.scss file there is this code

```
.btn-a {
   background: #777;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   font-size: 1em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn-b {
   @extend .btn-a;
   background: #ff0;
}
.sidebar .btn-a {
   text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

And then the output CSS in application.css is

```
.btn-a,
.btn-b {
   background: #777;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   font-size: 1em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn-b {
   background: #ff0;
}
.sidebar .btn-a,
.sidebar .btn-b {
   text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

K Now as to the question that I have ... I am not understanding why application.css gains the `.sidebar .btn-b` section. I think this is a pretty important concept to understand because this example is being used to introduce placeholder selectors. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like .btn-b gains *all* the style that are declared for .btn-a regardless of the order in which they are declared.

I've played around with this and come up with an alternative:

SASS

```
.btn{
   background: #777;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   font-size: 1em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn-a {
    @extend .btn;
text-transform: lowercase;
}
.btn-b {
   @extend .btn;
   background: #ff0;
}
```

CSS

```
.btn, .btn-a, .btn-b {
  background: #777;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-a {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.btn-b {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

This introduces a *dummy* class of .btn (could be called anything) which of course isn't used but it does supply the 'building blocks' for your other buttons.

Comment: +1 for extra code showing an example of a tidier `@extend`. Most of us have been surprised to find that `@extend` is quite greedy.

Comment: Thanks so much! In the course I am taking, the code that I used in my above question was actually being used to show us the use/importance of the "dummy" trick, but it was the fact that ".btn-b gains all the style that are declared for .btn-a **regardless of the order in which they are declared**" that I couldn't figure out. You've been a great help.

Answer (score 2):

When you extend a class, you're basically adding your selector everywhere that class is used.

```
.class {}
.wrapper .class {}

.extender {
  @extend .class;
}
```

Generates:

```
.class,
.extender {}
.wrapper .class,
.wrapper .extender {}
```

The best way around this problem is to use a placeholder selector.

```
%class,
.class {}
.wrapper .class {}

.extender {
  @extend %class;
}
```

Which generates:

```
.extender,
.class {}
.wrapper .class {}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. While I get this in theory, I have not encountered it in the field, so to speak, and I hope I will be able to recognize an opportunity for this approach.